# EF: Creating tables in OnModelCreating that aren't tracked by EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to create some tables by executing some SQL that Entity Framework should not be aware of, in the `OnModelCreating` method (overridden):

```
// This code creates the Auxiliary tables task
Trace.TraceInformation("Creating auxiliary tables.");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(GetResourceStream(String.Concat("My.Namespace.Resources.","CREATE_AUX_TABLES.SQL")))) {
    int i;
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    do {
        i = reader.Read();

        if (i > 0) {
            builder.Append((char) i);

            if (i == 0x3B) {
                string sql = builder.ToString().Trim();
                Trace.WriteLine("Submitting SQL:");
                Trace.WriteLine(sql);
                Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
                builder.Clear();
            }
        }
    } while (i > 0);
}
```

I am getting an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the
>   model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is
>   used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance
>   is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance
>   members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be
>   thread safe.

How can I create these tables only when the model is first created?

Comment: Does the method `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);` use the entity framework? I would think that the error message above is fairly self explanatory. You may not use the context inside of `OnModelCreating` or concurrently access the context in multiple threads.

Comment: I resolved it by having this SQL execution in the Seed() method of the DbContextInitializer

Comment: I don't think your question was particularly clear in the first place, but glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Added SQL execution in the `Seed()` method of the DbContextInitializer.